# Google Play service error- IllegalStateException

Tags: android, google-play-services, version, google-vision

I'm trying to use the Google mobile vision API but when I start to use it I have the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 9877000 but found 6587000.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:

Here you can see my manifest I added the meta data

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ocr"/>
```

But when I check the value of the google play service version i have two files

- version.xml with 6587000
- values.xml with 9877000

In my gradle file I have:

- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'

Do you have any idea where does it comes from ?

Comment: because you have two separate version of same dependency , so remove the old one

Comment: Even if it is "protected non-project file" ?

Comment: try it , otherwise  post your app.gradle file and related details (protected non-project file)?

Answer (score 0):

bump up the version of play services dependency to 9.8.0

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```